# Where can I find a better pinout diagram for "Arduino Ethernet" board?

Tags: pins, ethernet

I'm looking for a complete pinout of the [Arduino Ethernet R3](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardEthernet).
I've found one [here](http://f1mvp.perso.sfr.fr/Robotic/arduino.htm) which is low quality, and seems not complete (where are the digital I/O pins?).

[image]

BTW, it was not a good idea for Arduino to name this board "Arduino Ethernet", as this is pretty useless for searching online :-(

Comment: ... What? The digital I/O pins are the cyan ones...

Comment: The pinout is Arduino Uno compatible, except for pins 10-13

Comment: Clicking on the image on Arduino's site reveals a much higher resolution version.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin: Not sure what you mean. The low quality I 'complain about' is for the image in the question (board with pinout, not an image of the board itself), which is not on the Arduino site. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a better one from :

https://pinoutguide.com/images/arduino/ethernet.png

This one also presents the Arduino Ethernet R3 board and 
has the extra I2C pins (SCK=A5,SDA=A4) next to the AREF pin.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [formal Arduino.cc website](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardEthernet) mentions, somewhat obscurely, that the Arduino Ethernet is pin compatible with Arduino Uno:

> The Revision 3 of the board introduces the standardized 1.0 pinout

Except for pins 10-13:

> Pins 10, 11, 12 and 13 are reserved for interfacing with the Ethernet
>   module and should not be used otherwise. This reduces the number of
>   available pins to 9, with 4 available as PWM outputs.

The other difference is the onboard LED is connected to pin 9 rather than the Uno's pin 13:

> On most other arduino boards, this LED is found on pin 13. It is on pin 9 on the Ethernet board because pin 13 is used as part of the SPI connection.

You can use any Arduino Uno pinout diagram as a reference, the [one you have found](http://marcusjenkins.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ARDUINO_V2.png) seems to be pretty elaborated.

Comment: Except that it does: "The Revision 3 of the board introduces the standardized 1.0 pinout..."